# Translate regex from JavaScript to ColdFusion?

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion

Hello everyone I have regular expressions that I created in JavaScript and now I would like to have them in ColdFusion. Few problems I run into while trying to put this in ColdFusion, first one was with the blank values. If my variable is empty my regex was outputting `false`. Second problem is combining these regex in one big line that will check entire row of my text file. For some reason my regex was ignoring upper/lower case. If I have only lower case my regex was outputting true even that is not allowed in this case. Here is my regex:

```
<cfset fileRegex = "^(?i)^ *[a-z][a-z' .,-]{0,49} *\t(?i) *[a-z][a-z' .,-]{0,49} *\t *(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2} *\t(?i) *([M|F]) *\t(?i) *(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|[A-Z]{1,2}) *\t *([^\t].{0,50}) *\t(?i) *([A-Z0-9 ,]{1,102})? *\t *\d{10} *(\t[^\t]*){22}\t *([0-9]{1,4}) *\t([^\t]*)(\t *[A-Z ',.-]{1,50} *)?$">

<cfset myData = "John   Terry   1/29/1981   M   0   London  NULL    0129198109  609 8000    1   England">

<cfif REFind(fileRegex,myData,true) GT 0>
    true<br>
<cfelse>
    false<br>
</cfif>
```

So in this case last word in my Data set is `England` and my regex should accept upper case only and it does not, second problem is if I leave this field empty I will get `False` in return. Also this last word is optional and if I erase that together with the tab I should get `true`. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know.

Comment: [Your regex just does not match the string.](https://regex101.com/r/RchZSn/1) The `(\t[^\t]*){22}` requires 22 columns. If you replace it with `(\t[^\t]*){0,22}` it will work. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/RchZSn/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that will make my 22 columns optional I guess?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Note you have many `(?i)` inside, that is not necessary. One single `(?i)` at the start of the pattern is enough. Also, `|` inside `[M|F]` should be removed as it is parsed as a literal pipe  symbol.

Comment: I have many of them because in some case upper\lower case should be ignored in other case not. Also I did not understand problem with the pipe and how that should look like? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `[M|F]` matches 1 of 3 characters: either `M`, `|`, or `F`. I do not understand what you need to match in the end.

Comment: I need letter m or f either in lower or upper case.

Comment: But the `(?i)` does it, doesn't it? https://regex101.com/r/RchZSn/4

Comment: I figured that your solution can be applied. I will put just one (?i) in front of the ^ on the beginning. Later on the insert in SQL I can handle upper case fields. This will help to increase efficiency of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex requires 22 columns with `(\t[^\t]*){22}`. You may make them optional (-> `(\t[^\t]*){0,22}`) and the regex will basically work:

```
(?i)^ *[a-z][a-z' .,-]{0,49} *\t *[a-z][a-z' .,-]{0,49} *\t *(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2} *\t *([MF]) *\t *(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|[A-Z]{1,2}) *\t *([^\t].{0,50}) *\t *([A-Z0-9 ,]{1,102})? *\t *\d{10} *(\t[^\t]*){0,22}\t *([0-9]{1,4}) *\t([^\t]*)(\t *[A-Z ',.-]{1,50} *)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RchZSn/5)

Some smaller enhancements:

- Note you have many `(?i)` inside, that is not necessary. One single `(?i)` at the start of the pattern is enough.
- `|` inside `[M|F]` should be removed as it is parsed as a literal pipe symbol. `[M|F]` matches 1 of 3 characters: either `M`, `|`, or `F`.
- Please also check if `/` should really be escaped, I doubt it needs escaping since there are no regex delimiters here.

Comment: If I remove pipe between M and F how I then will check for those two letters in regex? Also where I should check the forward slash /?

Comment: The `[...]` is a character class, not a grouping construct. `[ab]` = `(?:a|b)`. As for the slashes, I meant all cases of `\/`. Unlike JS, you do not have to escape slashes as they are not special chars in ColdFusion regex.